# How is Objcet.clone() knows which class must be cloned?

Tags: java, clone, cloneable

How is `clone()` method in `Object` class knows which class/fields must be cloned? For example how Objcet.super() can know that I need to serialize exactly `A` class or `B` class if I don't put any arguments in it?
`clone()` defined as `nativ` son I can not see it's implementstion

```
class A implements Cloneable
{
    public int a = 1;

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
class B extends A
{
    public int b = 2;

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: It copies all the fields in the object.